# I loaded .NET environment but dotnet is not recognized in command line when I write dotnet --version

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I loaded .NET SDK 6.0.100 (x64), .NET runtime 6.0.11(x64) and Windows desktop runtime but when I write `dotnet --version` I got dotnet is not recognized in command line. I restarted my pc and I added path in dotnet but problem wasn't solved. but problem was continued.

[image]
[image: dotnet is not recognized]
[image: path]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you have in the directory `C:\Program Files\dotnet`? Do you see dotnet.exe?

Comment: not have dotnet.exe why it not i dont know @K.A.

Comment: Uninstall .NET Runtime and .NET SDK (all versions), and reinstall this: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.403-windows-x64-installer. After installation, open a new command prompt and run the `dotnet` command.

Comment: You need to find the folder where `dotnet.exe` is located, and add it to the environment variables. If you successfully installed .Net, you can use `where dotnet` to see the location.If you can't find it, I suggest you refer to K. A. ‘s comment to uninstall and reinstall.